# Import a vcf file without using an intent android programically

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

how to import the `vcf` file without using this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/x-vcard");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "import"? You want to have a reference of it in your code? Do you want to show it or use it without and Intent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EzVcard library : https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard

With `Ezvcard.parse(vCardFile).first()`, you can parse a file in a vcard format.